# 6 players on the court during free throw

Tags: rules, basketball

A team had six players on the court during the first of two free throws. The extra player was removed before the second free throw attempt.

Is this a technical violation or was the time during the first free throw a dead ball period?

Comment: Could you specify which rule set you are interested in? (FIBA, NBA or something else) - this is the kind of edge case where it can matter.